# Resetting a React-Native WebView Window

Tags: react-native, android-studio, web, view

I have a simple web view setup within react-native

I have nav bar at the bottom and the links open different screens with web views, however the pages save state. SO let's say I navigate to an internal page on the website (so like the about page of the website) when I go onto another screen and come back to the screen - the url state is saved. How can I make it so when I click on the nav button it always redirects to me to the initial page loaded in the web view...I've committed links etc as its sensitive data.

USE CASE:

User opens app, is greeted with a homepage - they can click links on the homepage which takes them to another part of the web page - if they navigate away from the Home Screen (within the app) then go back to the Home Screen on the app - the web view is on the last internal page they were on.

I want it so when they press the home button on the nabber on the app it effectively resets the web view?

Thanks

Code below:

```
const url = "websitelinkere.com/pageLink.html";
...
<View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
   <WebView
      javaScriptEnabled={true}
      domStorageEnabled={true}
      mixedContentMode={'compatibility'}
        source={{
        //meta type & http header locking for aded security
        uri: url, //<-- I want it to always load pageLink.html <-- even if I've navigated to pageLinkDifferent.html
      }}
      onMessage={(event) => {}}
   />       
</View>
```

Navbar (example link):

```
<View style={homePage.column}>
   <TouchableOpacity onPress={() => navigation.navigate('JournalHome')}>
      <Image style={homePage.navImage} source={journalHomeImage}/>
   </TouchableOpacity>
</View>
```

I've tried researching the issue on stack overflow and online but haven't found a solution that works for me

Answer (score 0):

you can use `useFocusEffect` in react-navigation

```js
const INITIAL_URL = "websitelinkere.com/pageLink.html";
...
const webviewRef = useRef();
const [url,setUrl] = useState(INITIAL_URL)
...
 useFocusEffect(
    React.useCallback(() => {
      if(webviewRef.current) {
         setUrl(INITIAL_URL);
          webviewRef.current.reload();
      }
    }, [])
  );
...
<Webview 
ref={webviewRef}
source={{ uri }}
/>
```

Comment: Hi - Thanks for this :-) - I'm really new to this - I get a can't find variable useRef(); - so I've figured I need to create function somewhere called useref() - but what is actually meant to go there :-)

Comment: Actually I'm a spoon!!! I haven't imported it

Comment: @JackWright You can import useRef from react.